# selecting rows that meet two criteria at the same time in the same column (pandas)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame  that looks like this:

```
data = {'site' : ['a.com','d.com','d.com','b.com','b.com ',' c.com',c.com','c.com'], 'type' : [ 3, 1,3,1,1,1,3,3]}

sites= pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['site', 'type'])
```

some sites are type 1 and some are type 3, but there are some sites which have type 1 and type 3. I would like to change the type to another number when the site has two types such as c.com. It can be 2 or 4 or any other number. My desired output will be like this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/305vz.png)
I am really new to pandas, and I am really stuck. My problem is that I do not know how to select the sites that have 1 and 3 in the column type.

I tried:

```
sites['site']=np.where[(sites.type == 1)&(sites.type == 3)], 2, sites['type'])
```

but I got an error:

```
builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable.
```

I do not what other function I can use or how to achieve what I want.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please explain **clearly** your logic. For example, does the first row go from 1 to 3?

Comment: You can't possibly have a df that looks like that, the strings aren't even nested correctly

Comment: Sorry I edited the data frame first row. What I meant is that some websites are repeated and some are not. In the case of a.com only appears one time and get value of 3. Then d.com and c.com are repeated and get values of 1 and 3 in type. Finally there are some websites that are repeated such as b.com that are type 1 only. Hence, I have some websites that are pure type 1 and some pure type 3, but some websites that are type 1 and 3. So, I want to distinguish the websites that get type 1 and 3 from the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select **sites** that have both **1** and **3** types by using `sites[(sites.type == 1)&(sites.type == 3)]` since this expression allways equals False as pointed out by **jpp**. A better way to do it would be :

```
sites = pd.DataFrame(
 {'site' : ['a.com','d.com','d.com','b.com','b.com ', 'c.com' , 'c.com' , 
                                                             'c.com'],
  'type' : [ 3, 1,3,1,1,1,3,3]}, columns = ['site', 'type'])

temp = sites.groupby("site", as_index = False).nunique() # Count the number of 
                                                      #types for each site
temp.columns = ["site", "nunique_type"] # rename 
new_sites = sites.merge(temp, on = "site") # merge both dataframes
new_sites.loc[new_sites.nunique_type >=2, "type"] = 10 # Give new type to 
                          # sites with more than two different types
```

Comment: I ran this and it doesn't appear to have any effect on the data frame.

Comment: Surely, `(sites.type == 1)&(sites.type == 3)` will always evaluate to a series of `False` values, and therefore the query is *guaranteed* to do nothing.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what is desired I'm not sure this works to the desired specification. Your solution presumes that if there are multiple entries for a site that it should be coded as 10. However the requirement is that if there are multiple entries AND they have different type values, then they get a different type code. In some instances there are multiple entries (b.com) that have the same value that your solution has coded as 10 but should be left alone. Check the desired output linked to see what I mean.

Comment: ....actually looking at the desired output I'm not sure I understand the logic behind the requirement either as not all 'c.com' values have been switched to 2....

Comment: Yeah James Allen-Robertson, you're right. The `count()` must be replaced by `nunique` and everything would be fine then.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This was a tricky one but I think I got it...

Group the data by the site name and then get the `nunique()` or number of unique values of the `type` column for each site. If there is more than one unique value you know that site has two different types listed in the data frame at some point.

```
g = sites.groupby('site')['type'].nunique()

    site
a.com    1
b.com    1
c.com    2
d.com    2
Name: type, dtype: int64
```

We then use this to select the sites that have more than 1 unique number of type values, and select the index to get a list of site names.

```
dup_sites = g[g >1].index

> Index(['c.com', 'd.com'], dtype='object', name='site')
```

Now use this list by selecting all rows of `sites` where the value of the `site` column `isin` the `dup_sites` list, select the `type` column and replace the value, here we use 9.

```
sites.loc[sites.site.isin(dup_sites),'type'] = 9

site    type
0   a.com   3
1   d.com   9
2   d.com   9
3   b.com   1
4   b.com   1
5   c.com   9
6   c.com   9
7   c.com   9
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This does exactly what I wanted :). I chose this answer since it is more simple and elegant.